# Why did Hajime Nagumo entered a second Labyrinth?

Tags: arifureta

Hajime Nagumo wish was to escape the labyrinth he was in and then go home. Why then did he enter a second Labyrinth with Yue after that?

Comment: I haven't seen the anime but it read the manga long back and i think it was to train

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After they were summoned, the Pope Ishtar told them that regular people can't perform interdimensional magic, that the God Ehit was the one who summoned them, and only he could bring them back to their world.

When they find Oscar Orcus' remains in his hideout at the end of the first labyrinth and are bestowed with Creation Magic (an Age of Gods Magic), they are told that the other labyrinths also contain other Age of Gods Magics, so Hajime deduces that his best chance at finding a way back home is collecting the Age of Gods Magic sealed in the labyrinths in the off-chance that one of them has some sort of inter-dimensional application.